Applicability of the $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ pre-factor for Coulomb Attraction in Nanocrystals
I am currently working on a thesis and stumbled upon a seemingly formal issue which I was not able to resolve myself.
In short
The classical coulomb energy between two charges (let's say, electrons for simplicity) at distance r from each other is:
$$\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r}\cdot \frac{e^2}{r}$$
For semiconductor nanocrystals, where quantum confinement is to be considered, I often find an expression for the lowest energy exciton which contains a term for the coulomb attraction that is:
$$\frac{1.8e^2}{\epsilon r}$$
Exemplary reference:
https://doi.org/10.1021/j100403a003
https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.matsci.30.1.475
In these cases, $\epsilon$ is commonly referred to as "dielectric constant". The factor "1.8" is said to be a numerically determined constant.
Own assessment
I am (to some extent) familiar with the CGS vs. SI unit problematic. However, I see two possible interpretations of the expression stated above, between which I cannot distinguish as no publication or text book that I found so far elaborates on the unit system used or the derivation of the numeric constant. I can see the following interpretations:

The expression is in SI units. In that case, it is $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 \cdot \epsilon_r$. This would mean that the factor $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ is included in the value of "1.8".
The expression is in CGS units. In that case, it is $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ and $\epsilon= \epsilon_r$. This means the value "1.8" is independent of the fraction pre-factor.

I cannot not tell these two options apart.
Hopefully, some of you can shed a light on the matter or elaborate on the derivation of the "1.8" pre-factor in the lowest state energy estimation.

The (freely available online) paper Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2011 Jan 18; 108(3): 965–970 includes the sentence "For charge carriers residing in the $1S$ states, the Coulomb attraction is $E_C = 1.8q^2/4\pi \epsilon\epsilon_0 D$, where $D$ is the QD radius and the numerical constant 1.8 arises from integration of the $1S$ eigenfunctions," which supports your option 2 (in other words, "my" paper is clearly using SI units, so apparently "yours" are using CGS units). I also hope the comment about the $1S$ eigenfunction is useful.

As a caveat I don't know the underlying physics and am not sure that this paper is talking about exactly the same thing you are, I'm relying on the similarity of the key words and the numerical coincidence of $1.8$, so please do check if you agree that the context of the paper as the same as what you need, if you use that comment.

The provided paper deals with the exact same topic. The comment on the eigenfunction is helpful, too. I will thus take option two for granted. Still puzzles me how people can just jump back and forth between SI and CGS units within single text book chapters without even adding a note to it. Thanks!

I'm also annoyed (although not surprised) when a field reaches a point when people don't feel the need to give a citation for a mysterious factor, like 1.8 in this case, since "everyone knows that."

Resolution based on the commentary by Andrew.
The equation in question is the coulomb attraction between electron and hole of the 1s exciton in a quantum dot:
$$\frac{1.8e^2}{\epsilon r}$$
The questioner wonders, whether this equation is expressed in SI units or CGS units.
The question can be answered based on two publicly available papers:

In Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2011 Jan 18; 108(3): 965–970, the same equation is derived in SI units as:
$$E_c=\frac{1.8q^2}{4 \pi \epsilon \epsilon_0 D}$$
As in both equations $\epsilon$ is defined as the permittivity of the semiconductor, comparison of the equations indicates $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ which is the standard definition of the constant in the CGS unit system as described in the question as "Interpretation 2".

In Solid State Communications 59(6):405-408 the numerical prefactor expressed in the questioned equation as "1.8" is calculated as:
$$2-\frac{1}{\pi} \cdot (Si(2 \pi)-\frac{1}{2}Si(4 \pi)) \approx 1.786$$
Where $Si(x)$ is the sine-integral function.
This indicates that $ \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ is not part of the numerical prefactor as would be required by "Interpretation 1".


In conclusion, "Interpretation 2" mentioned in the original question is correct. The equation in question is expressed in CGS units.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
